# C++ inline ASM loop

Tags: assembly, x86, inline-assembly

I have the following piece of code:

```
        mov cx,10
    l1: 
    mov eax,1
    push eax
    mov eax, offset format
    push eax
    call DWORD ptr [printf]
    pop ebx
    pop ebx
    dec cx
    jnz l1
```

The problem is that it never exits the loop!
Does printf mess with the cx register or what?

Comment: What did you observe when you ran this in the debugger?

Comment: Yeah.. Debugger output would help in this case. Also, you could push the whole register set into the stack, printf and then pop it out again..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

printf follows the cdecl calling convention for which the following is true:

"The values in registers EAX, ECX, and EDX do not need to be preserved, whereas the others do."

Therefore, try to push cx, which is the lower half of ecx